# Laravel 4 file upload error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an file upload form, and I want to use validator.

```
$roles = array(
    'title' => 'required|max:128',
    'description' => 'required|max:2800',
    'picture' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
);
```

My problem is, if I try to upload a picture, I get this error: `finfo::finfo(): Failed to load magic database at ''`. The `$_SERVER['MAGIC']` is set to `/usr/share/misc/magic`... So I don't know why throw  this error. But if I comment out the picture validation line, and I select a photo is the form, I also get an error: `Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed`.
Can anybody tell me what should I do?

### UPDATE

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$filename = public_path() . '/images/test.png';
var_dump($finfo->file($filename));
```

It works good `string(9) "image/png"`. But in the validation still bad.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) for file validation and `finfo` needs `magic_file` name of a magic database file, usually something like /path/to/magic.mime. In your `php.ini` make sure you have something like this available and it points qo the right resource

```
[mime_magic]
mime_magic.magicfile = "D:\xampp\php\extras\magic.mime"
```

This is the path for the file in my `xampp` installation. It may varies depending on your `OS` and If not specified, the MAGIC environment variable is used, for more information, visit [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php). Also, [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=56999) may help you. It's not related to `Laravel` but your `php` installation.

Comment: I tryed to put it into my php.ini, but when laravel shows the error, it prints out: `REDIRECT_MAGIC /usr/share/misc/magic`. The magic file is available in that path. If I set something else in the php.ini, in the error still show this path. The weird thing is laravel says ... at '', so path is empty?!

Comment: Originally there isn't this line in php.ini